# How Heroku finds out if process has failed to start?

Tags: heroku

Does anybody knows explicit criteria that Heroku uses to tell that application hasn't started in 60s? Which URLs it ping? Which response codes considered acceptable? I couldn't find such details in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For web dynos the measure is the amount of time it takes for something on the dyno to bind to `$PORT`

Comment: This is true for R10 - Boot timeout error. But there's also H20 - App boot timeout error which can happen even if application has binded to the port already.